# How to multiply 2 different dataframe which have different shape but same header and row label in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Dataframe - 1 (number of products by country)**

**Note:** Use below code to generate example dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Devices':['Mobile','Mobile','Mobile','Mobile','Mobile','Laptop','Desktop'],'Sources':['India','India','India','India','UK','UK','US'],'Status':['ok','ok','notok','ok','ok','notok','ok'],'10/01/2020':[45,45,60,56,50,65,50],'10/02/2020':[45,60,56,56,50,65,50],'10/03/2020':[45,60,56,56,50,65,50],'10/04/2020':[45,60,56,15,25,26,20]})
```

Looks like blow:

[image]

**Data Freame - 2 (MRP of product by country)**

**Note:** Use below code to generate example dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Devices':['Mobile','Mobile','Laptop','Desktop'],'Sources':['India','UK','UK','US'],'Status':['MRP','MRP','MRP','MRP'],'10/01/2020':[8000,8200,7800,8500],'10/02/2020':[8200,6500,7900,8000],'10/03/2020':[7800,13000,12500,7800],'10/04/2020':[8500,7800,21000,8500]})
```

Looks like blow:

[image]

I want to multiply df2 with df1 data, Name and number of column would be same on both dataframe. Devices and sources is common key between both dataframe.

I have tried few code to multipy both dataframe but it doesn't work. it is giving me `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`

```
df1.mul(df2.values)
```

New df1 After multiplying df2 value:(desired output)

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Devices` and `Sources` as the index and then multiply

```
df1.set_index(['Devices', 'Sources', 'Status'])[df1.columns[3:]].mul(df2.set_index(['Devices', 'Sources'])[df2.columns[3:]]).reset_index()

   Devices Sources Status  10/01/2020  10/02/2020  10/03/2020  10/04/2020
0  Desktop      US     ok      425000      400000      390000      170000
1   Laptop      UK  notok      507000      513500      812500      546000
2   Mobile   India     ok      360000      369000      351000      382500
3   Mobile   India     ok      360000      492000      468000      510000
4   Mobile   India  notok      480000      459200      436800      476000
5   Mobile   India     ok      448000      459200      436800      127500
6   Mobile      UK     ok      410000      325000      650000      195000
```

Comment: this is giving an error because you set "Status" as index, I am able to run it successfully if remove Status from Index. How can I get back this column?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? You should not have a problem setting status as the index as well with the latest version of pandas

Comment: I am using Anaconda notebook and panda packages is '0.23.4'

Comment: That version of pandas is about two years old . . . may be time to update or create a virtual environment with the latest version of pandas

Comment: yes, you are right, I have checked in latest version and its working fine.